# ForEach-Object calling property of csv file changing from no white space to having whitespace

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Due to a recent change, this is pretty much a continuation from this - [Remove leading zeros in csv file from int values only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278631/remove-leading-zeros-in-csv-file-from-int-values-only)

I have the following code:

```
Import-CSV "C:\path\test.csv" | ForEach-Object{
    $_.column1 = ($_.column1).TrimStart('0')
    $_
} | Export-Csv "C:\path\test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
Move-Item "C:\path\test2.csv" "C:\path\test.csv" -Force
```

After trying the following code:

```
Import-CSV "C:\path\test.csv" | ForEach-Object{
    $_.column 1 = ($_.column 1).TrimStart('0')
    $_
} | Export-Csv "C:\path\test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
Move-Item "C:\path\test2.csv" "C:\path\test.csv" -Force
```

Now, in the csv file `column1` has been changed to `column 1` (now has a whitespace).

I get a compilation syntax error:

```
Unexpected token 'One' in expression or statement.
At :line:2 char:19
+       $_.Column One  <<<< = ($_.Column One).TrimStart('0')
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated...

Comment: Did you try `$_['column 1']` ? Although, having said that - are you sure there isn't just an empty field in the CSV and it can't call TrimStart on a ... null string coming from the CSV ?

Comment: `$_.'column 1' = "$($_.'column 1')".TrimStart('0')`

Comment: I'm sorry guys. They also changed the csv filename on me, so I was pulling the wrong csv file (forgot to change the filename name in my code as well). I'm running it now, if it works I will delete this question. If it doesn't work, I will reconstruct the question to match what else went wrong. Thank you anyways for helping me look into this...

Comment: hmmm since i couldn't find anything like this on stack overflow (closest thing I found was a guy trying to assign it to a variable before using it). I'll go ahead and leave the question up here for others to search and find who need help with this. I'll just restructure the question and answer for others to see. Thanks both again for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found on this site:
http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/csv-fields-with-spaces-in-the-field-name/

```
Import-CSV "C:\path\test.csv" | ForEach-Object{
    $_.'column 1' = ($_.'column 1').TrimStart('0')
    $_
} | Export-Csv "C:\path\test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
Move-Item "C:\path\test2.csv" "C:\path\test.csv" -Force
```