# Modify certain section of csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file that has multiople lines, which uses "|" as delimiter as the following shows.

`MAIN|02/21/2018|7695154880|082.21|00021
 MAIN|02/21/2018|7695154880|000.21|00210`

I would like to remove the leading zeros of forth and fifth sections so the following shows desired result. Is there any way can do it in powershell? Thank you.

`MAIN|02/21/2018|7695154880|82.21|21
 MAIN|02/21/2018|7695154880|0.21|210`

Comment: You might carefully review the following help: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You've added the Powershell tag. Do you have some code to show? Whatfor do you need this? Leading zeros usually do not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Olaf here, including the zero thing. 
Yet, maybe it's just the visual thing for you.
Anyway, what you are asking for is similar to this post.

> Remove leading zeros in csv file from int values only
>
> I have this csv file I'm trying to remove leading zeros from
>
> [Remove leading zeros in csv file from int values only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278631/remove-leading-zeros-in-csv-file-from-int-values-only)

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought Regex like `[regex]::replace($value,'^(0+)','')`
But  - in my opinion it would be better just to do

```
$csv|Foreach-Object{$_.ValueTORemoveLeadingZeroesFrom=
[float]$_.ValueTORemoveLeadingZeroesFrom}
```

By casting string to float You actually get this done easier I think?

Comment: This answer also helps to solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: Or in a casting approach, this as well... [decimal]$_.ValueTORemoveLeadingZeroesFrom